# How to validate user raw_input against dictionary key: values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
username = raw_input()
password = raw_input()

user_acct = {'ADMIN':'PASSWORD','READONLY':'PASSWORD','READWRITE':'PASSWORD} 

if username and password != user_acct:
          print('Invalid Login... Please Try Again')
else:

          print('Correct Login')
```

Comment: With the above code, no matter what I type, 'Invalid Login... Please Try Again' is displayed

Comment: I don't know about Python, but I thought most languages required conditionals to be evaluated separately. `if a != b and c!=d:`. Also, isn't user_acct an array? You are testing whether an array equals a string, which will probably always be false.

Comment: Thank you for your input but this question was answered correctly last week with the code below.                                                                               if username in user_acct and password == user_acct[username]:
    print('Correct Login')
else:
    print('Invalid Login... Please Try Again')

Answer (score 0):

Python will lazily evaluate your if clause, that consists of two conditions!

`if username` will be `True` if it is not empty.

No need to check for the password then. As a result, `Invalid Login... Please Try Again` is printed.

You might want to

1. check if the username is a key in the dictionary
2. check it the password fits to this key

   ```
   if username in user_acct and password == user_acct[username]:
       print('Correct Login')
   else:
       print('Invalid Login... Please Try Again')
   ```

Comment: I made your changes and when I typed in the correct username and password, I got ('Invalid Login... Please Try Again'). So I entered a incorrect username and password, I got 'Correct Login'). It's like reverse logic.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't flip the print statements in my correction. Now it works as I wanted it to. Thank you. You're GREAT!